# Var1 is set to contents of command executed, how to set Var2 to be the command from Var1

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am looking to have 2 variables.

I already have a working setup like follows

```
var1="$(echo hello)"
```

When printed like below, it says "hello"

```
"${var1}" = "hello"
```

What I would like is

```
var2=$var1
```

When printed, displays "echo hello"

```
"${var2}" = "echo hello"
```

This may be logically impossible, as var1 is set to be the output of the command, **is there anyway I can set var2 to pull the command that sets var1 not the output of the command?**

Comment: No way. If you call `"${var1}"` it outputs `bash: hello: command not found`. Do you mean `var1="echo hello"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pull the command that generated the variable because the information is not there anymore.  Yet, you could delay when the command to generate `var1` is executed by using `eval`.  For example:

```
var1="echo hello"
echo "var1: $var1"

var2="$var1"
echo "var2: $var2"

var1=$(eval "$var1")
echo "var1: $var1"
```

Will print:

```
var1: echo hello
var2: echo hello
var1: hello
```

Since you can use `eval` to execute the command inside `var1` until the output of that command is needed you can keep the command itself in `var1`.

Although this is not a good coding practice.  In pretty much all cases it is better to have two variables: once holding the command and one holding the output.  Using `eval` is frowned upon, for several security, and general debugging problems.

---

On a side note, in this specific case where you have a command where the only shell special characters are whitespace, several shells will allow you to perform the subshell execution from variable without the need for `eval`, i.e. this will work in most shells:

```
var3=$($var1)
```

Works in `bash` and `ksh` variants.  Doesn't in `zsh` variants.

Comment: Scripting is so logical, I love it. Thanks! This will work great.

Comment: Yea after implementing it, I went back to the way I had it, which was var & cmd as separate variables. The idea was to make the script easier, but it ended up making the logic more confusing to read and not working well in all cases. Still, Good to know if needed.

Comment: You don't need eval here. `var2=$(var1)` is enough.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Correct, but you mean `var2=$($var1)` right?  That's a `bash`/`dash` thing as far as i'm aware.  Does not work in `zsh` for example (which would try to resolve `$var1` as a command without dropping the quotes first).

Comment: @grochmal Yes, I had a typo there. This works in `ksh93`/`pdksh` too, which are the shells I'm using.

Comment: @Kusalananda - Hmmm... It is a popular feature then.  I guess it deserves a note in the answer about it then.  Thanks

Comment: @Kusalananda `var2=$($var1)` is a horrible idea. I recommend erasing it from your brain. It only works because `$var1` happens to contain no shell special characters apart from whitespace. The way to execute a shell command stored in a variable is `eval "$var1"`. Running `$var1` in general just makes a mess.